# Dealing with ASCII errors and using .encode('utf-8')

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
test = open('HTMLDoc.html', 'rU')
soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'html.parser')
data = soup.findAll("li", { "class":"position" })
print data.encode('utf-8')
```

I keep getting the error `AttributeError: "'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'encode'"`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I realize that `data` is a BeautifulSoup Object

```
print type(data)
```

returns `class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'`

How do I print that out to see what the results are?

Comment: Try this: `print [str(x).encode('utf-8') for x in data]` or `for x in data: print str(x).encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to encode a list which is not possible. Try this out instead:

```
data = soup.findAll("li", { "class":"position" })
for d in data:
    print d.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: `print type(data)` returns `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`

Comment: findAll returns a list of all occurrences. Therefore, you need to iterate through the ResultSet before you are able to encode